# How do you fix reversed tab order in SwiftUI for MacOS? (key view loop)

Tags: macos, swiftui, tab-ordering

I have a window with some text fields and when tabbing between fields, focus moves from the bottom to top instead of top-down. How do you make it tab top-to-bottom?

```
var body: some View {
  VStack {
    TextField("First name", text: $firstName)
      .modifier(InputModifier())
    TextField("Last namee", text: $lastName)
      .modifier(InputModifier())
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `.focusable()` to the views and they will tab top-to-bottom.

```
var body: some View {
  VStack {
    TextField("First name", text: $firstName)
      .modifier(InputModifier())
      .focusable()
    TextField("Last name", text: $lastName)
      .modifier(InputModifier())
      .focusable()
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Is .focusable() working in the meanwhile on macOS. Did Apple fix it ?

Comment: Found the same, but I haven't found a way to reverse it: Shift-Tab should go bottom-to-top, but it doesn't (on macOS 10.15.1, Xcode 11.2.1)

Comment: Does this actually work? I'm on 10.15.4 with Xcode 11.4 GM but `focusable()` has no effect. When I hit tab, `TextFields` just give up focus and nothing else happens. This is in a playground, although I guess (hope) that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Works with MacOS NSTextViews embedded inside NSViewRepresentable. shift+tab to tab and control+shift+tab for reverse tab.